# multi-arity defn in Clojure -- first match first serve?

Tags: clojure, overloading, arity, defn

To be concrete, what is supposed to happen in the following situation:

```
(defn avg
  ([] 0)
  ([& args] (/ (reduce + args) (count args))))

(avg)
```

i.e., can I rely on clojure to always return 0 rather than divide-by-zero?

Comment: What happens when you try it in the REPL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* rely on Clojure to return 0 rather than divide-by-zero. But it isn't first match, first served:

```
(defn avg
  ([& args] (/ (reduce + args) (count args)))
  ([] 0))

(avg)
; 0
```

The specific arities take precedence over the *rest* argument, as described [here](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28fn%20name?%20%28%5Bparams%2a%20%5D%20exprs%2a%29%20%29).

Comment: Thank-you. I believe you, but I'm not seeing, or else not understanding, the description as such. Are you referring to this: "One and only one overload can itself be variadic, by specifying the ampersand followed by a single rest-param. Such a variadic entry point, **when called with arguments that exceed the positional params**, will find them in a seq contained in the rest param. If the supplied args do not exceed the positional params, the rest param will be nil."

Comment: @manualcrank My interpretation is: only if there are more arguments than *any* explicit arity encompasses is *the* version with the rest argument matched (I need sleep before further exegesis :( ).

Comment: Ok that makes sense here too, i.e. the variadic entry point is not taken in this example because no parameters does not exceed zero positional parameters.